# *ngFor used in <li> to bind the data received from API using angular version of 8.2.8,but could not display the data

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I would like to display the user title from the API using the angular js of version 8.2.8 and tried  to bind it in the `<ul>` and `<li>` with *ngFor .After converting the json values to Array format through this code as given below

search.component.ts :

```
getUsers()
  {
    this.githubservice.getUser(this.SearchText);
    this.SearchResult = this.githubservice.getUser(this.SearchText).subscribe(
      res => {
        res.json;
      }
    );
    this.SearchResult = Array.of(this.SearchResult);

  }
```

json data will be received in this format as given below:

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": false
  }
]
```

search.component.html :( trying to bind the json data stored in the variable SearchResult)

```
<span><input type="text" (keyup)="onKeyup($event)" /></span>
<span><input type="button" (click)="getUsers()" value="Search" /></span>
<p>{{SearchResult.title}}</p>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of SearchResult">{{SearchResult.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you need to probably go through the docs better and learn ngFor and ngIf

Comment: @AbhishekKothari here's a direct link to the documentation about structural directives: https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives, but I suspect just walking through the [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) would give a lot of the necessary information.

Comment: @robsiemb atleast the guy would know the *ngFor is for loop and *ngIf is for conditions. He has got even that part wrong

Comment: @robsiemb, Abhishek Kothari , i had shared the  code snippet after editing it now ,please help me  out to  know how to bind the data in html (search.component.html)

Comment: Inside the loop, you need to refer to "user" not "SearchResult".  See the example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

See [this example from the heros tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor), and [this more complete documentation](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-ngfor/).

You have placed the loop inside the ngIf directive, but it belongs inside the ngFor.  The ngIf should only be testing a boolean condition if it is needed.

For the loop itself, you need this to look something like:

```
<ol>
<li *ngFor="let user of SearchResult">{{ user.login }}</li>
</ol>
```

You can't just put the field name inside the ngFor.

If this doesn't answer the question, please provide a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the code in context.

Comment: i  have  data from an  API for example "https://api.github.com/search/users?q=js"  ,so storing it in the variable SearchResult declared as public   and this is the code as follows this.SearchResult = this.githubservice.getUser(js).subscribe
      (res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.SearchResult = res;
      });

Comment: @selvaanand please read the link about what is involved in a minimal reproducable example -- just the data is not sufficient, it would also require code that could be run to demonstrate the issue you have.  This could probably be reproduced without the API if the answer above doesn't solve it.